# MyFirebaseMessagingService android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I get an error message in the first line of the following code(AndroidManifest.xml):

```
 <service android:name="crc64572fdef0b95375c7.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

/Users/.../obj/Debug/net6.0-android/AndroidManifest.xml(5,5): Error AMM0000:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#crc64572fdef0b95375c7.MyFirebaseMessagingService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

I have read the link but I don't know what I should change in my project.
The error came after switching from an older Android version to the newer version 31 in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="31" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
```

What should I change in my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: did you try to add `android:exported=true` to the `service` in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the error message anymore after changing it to <service
android:name="crc64572fdef0b95375c7.MyFirebaseMessagingService" 
android:exported="false">. Should I use android:exported=true or android:exported=false? In another question they used android:exported=false.

Comment: It depends. By default (no set in manifest) it was exported=true. It's ok to leave it as it is only if you want other apps to have access to your service. I believe it can be set to false if you're not sure.

Answer (score 5):

For Xamarin forms, you have to go to your FirebaseMessagingService class, in my case it's called "PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService", add to the [Service] attribute exported=false or exported=true, it will look like this [Service (Exported =false)]

```
    namespace App1.Droid.Services
{
    [Service (Exported =false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService
```